# Linear combination of functions in C++

Tags: c++, boost, functor, higher-order-functions

Let's say we have the following:

```
// some functions
double f1( double x );
double f2( double x );
double f3( double x );
// coefficients
double c1, c2, c3;
// input variable
double x;
```

We need to calculate

[image]

We could use the direct approach which is

```
double y = c1*f1(x) + c2*f2(x) + c3*f3(x);  // x is passed 3 times as an argument
```

but that is not what I am trying to achieve. I need this operation to be performed in functor terms, i.e. with *higher-order-functions*. In pseudocode it must be something like this:

```
auto F = c1*f1 + c2*f2 + c3*f3; // resulting functor
double y = F(x);                // one and only passing the x value instead of 3 times
```

Is there a way I could achieve this with standard C++ library or with Boost, for example Boost.HOF? Or could you advice me another library where this is implemented? It is not necessary for the code to look exactly like this. The main thing is defining and applying arithmetic operations to functions instead of numbers and passing the x value only once.

Comment: You want to construct `F` in run-time, because you don't know what it should look like in compile-time?

Comment: It's possible, but is going to require some work and unintuitive operator overloading. It'll be quite complex and possibly slower, so what's the underlying reason for this? If it's just because it's better syntax, then I'd argue going against it, because template magic makes many things harder in the long run

Comment: *"passing the x value only once"* -- This is unlikely to be what you mean. The value will be passed once into your functor, once into `f1`, once into `f2`, and once into `f3`, for a total of four times being passed. I think you mean that you want to be able to invoke the composed function with a single function call (which would have only one parameter naturally).

Comment: The answer may vary depending on the fact that you want to achieve the result at compile time, maybe using variadic templates, or a run-time, maybe combining the vector with coefficients and the vector with functions (std::function, delegate and so on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [Boost.Phoenix](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/index.html). It lets you write lazy functions and also defines operators on them.

Given your example, you would be able to write the linear combination as close as possible to the mathematical notation:

```
auto x = boost::phoenix::arg_names::arg1;
double c1 = 0, c2 = 1, c3 = 2;

auto y = c1 * f1(x) + c2 * f2(x) + c3 * f3(x);
```

After this code, `y` is a callable taking one argument and lazily computing the targeted linear combination.

```
double y1 = y(1);
double y2 = y(2);
```

All you need to do for this to work, is make phoenix know about the functions with the following statements:

```
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(int, f1, f1, 1);
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(int, f2, f2, 1);
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(int, f3, f3, 1);
```

For a full example, have a look at [this](https://godbolt.org/z/5337scGWa) live example on godbolt.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you use lambda expressions for higher-order functions in C++, although they're not strictly necessary:

```cpp
double c1 = 1, c2 = 2, c3 = 3;
auto F = [c1, c2, c3](double x) {
    return c1 * f1(x) + c2 * f2(x) + c3 * f3(x);
};
double result = F(5);
```

See [What is a lambda expression, and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7627098/5740428)

What this creates is similar to:

```cpp
struct __lambda {
    double c1, c2, c3;
    double operator()(double x) const {
        return c1 * f1(x) + c2 * f2(x) + c3 * f3(x);
    }
};
```

If you need a type-erased interface, you can store the lambda in a `std::function`:

```cpp
std::function<double(double)> F = /* lambda ... */;
```

Lambda expressions all correspond to a unique closure type, and that is inconvenient at times.

Comment: Thank you. I must provide some more info then, which seems to discard the lambda approach. We may conditionally want to change the *functor*'s body by adding some more terms into its formula later within totally distinct code modules. So you won't know the exact body of the function in advance. After the *functor* is eventually constructed we will apply it to `x`.

Comment: @soad: C++ does not provide any way of modifying code dynamically at runtime, so if you want that, you'll need to do something completely different.  Generally, implement an interpreter for functions using whatever internal representation is most appropriate for what you are trying to do.  You'll then need to translate your input (text?) into that internal representation and execute it with your interpreter.

Comment: @soad so you're building the expression that the function computes at run-time? That basically means you're including a script engine in your program. Just look into JS or Python engines for C++. Otherwise you have to make a basic interpreter from scratch, basically.

Comment: @soad *"I must provide some more info then, which seems to discard the lambda approach."* -- This is a case of a correct answer revealing that the question you asked is not what you intended to ask. A recommended approach in this case is to thank the author (accept and/or upvote), then create a new post with the question you intended to ask. *By the way, the new question would need a more detailed and precise description of your requirements than can fit in a comment.*